# Condition in Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm about to get mad because of those conditions in JavaScript. Why this one doesn't work?

```
if (isNaN(first) || isNaN(second) && (act !== '-' || act !== '+'))
```

It should check is first is number, second is number and act is minus or plus. It's all right with numbers but it doesn't check act correct. What's wrong?

E.g. first is 1, act is a, second is 2. It won't work.

**P.S.**

I've some knowledge in C++ and Java. I've never had any problems with it. But since the time I've started to learn Javascript, I get so many mistakes like this.

Is there different system of such expressions?

Comment: "does not work" is not a problem description. JS always works as intended, sometimes its intention does not match with your though.

Comment: Define "not working". What are the values of `first`, `second` and `act`, what result do you get **and what result do you expect instead**?

Comment: `act !== '-' || act !== '+'` will always be true regardless of the value of `act`. No, that's not a Javascript annoyance, it's basic logic.

Comment: `(act !== '-' || act !== '+')` is always true. This has nothing to do with JS; it's simple logic.

Comment: `(act !== '-' || act !== '+')` is ALWAYS true

Comment: Has anyone mentioned yet that `act !== '-' || act !== '+'` is always true?

Comment: I'm continually amazed how after so many comments OPs can "clarify" a question again with another "won't work"... -_-;;

Comment: Indeed. Didn't mentioned it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

> It should check is first is number, second is number and act is minus or plus. It's all right with numbers but it doesn't check act correct.

Thus for the requirement stated above the correct statement would be

```
if ( !isNaN(first) && !isNaN(second) && (act == '-' || act == '+'))
```

---

If you want to invert the condition, that would be

```
if ( !(!isNaN(first) && !isNaN(second) && (act == '-' || act == '+')))
```

which is [equivalent to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
if ( isNaN(first) || isNaN(second) || (act != '-' && act != '+'))
```